# Python list comprehension for three-dimensional array

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a three dimensional array in this format:

```
x = [
    [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]],
[[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]],
[[21,22,23,24,25],[26,27,28,29,30]],
[[21,22,23,24,25]]
]
```

I'd like to split it into two, three dimensional arrays in this format:

```
y = [
    [[1,2,3],[6,7,8]],
[[11,12,13],[16,17,18]],
[[21,22,23],[26,27,28]],
[[21,22,23]]
]

z = [
    [[4,5],[9,10]],
[[14,15],[19,20]],
[[24,25],[29,30]],
[[24,25]]
]
```

I came up with this list comprehension for creating y:

```
[j[:3] for i in x for j in i]
```

Which returns this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8], [11, 12, 13], [16, 17, 18], [21, 22, 23], [26, 27, 28], [31, 32, 33]]
```

But as you'll see, it doesn't maintain the same multi-dimensional shape.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: is using numpy (instead of a list comprehension) ok?

Comment: @PaulH Not sure if using numpy on a jagged list is better tho.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye for sure. you'd have to fill it with NaNs, and that'd convert the ints to floats, and then you'd have to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate one level deeper:

```
x = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]], [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]], [[21, 22, 23, 24, 25], [26, 27, 28, 29, 30]], [[21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]]
y = [[i[:3] for i in b] for b in x]
z = [[i[-2:] for i in b] for b in x]
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8]], [[11, 12, 13], [16, 17, 18]], [[21, 22, 23], [26, 27, 28]], [[21, 22, 23]]]
[[[4, 5], [9, 10]], [[14, 15], [19, 20]], [[24, 25], [29, 30]], [[24, 25]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your inner most loop into a nested comprehension so that the inner lists are preserved:

```
y = [[j[:3] for j in i] for i in x]
```